# htaccess force redirect based on cookie not working for sub-directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a folder for one of my domains `/site`. Here I have a `.htaccess` file with:

```
rewriteengine on
rewritebase /

rewritecond     %{HTTP_COOKIE}      !allow=asdx
rewriterule     ^.*$                    .set-cookie.php
```

Basicly I want to redirect all requests that do not have the allow cookie set to "asdx" to another file.

The problem is that I have folders like `/site/subdomain1` that have `.htaccess` files of their own (with `rewriteengine on`). Accessing one of these files renders the initial redirect (based on the cookie) useless. If I disable the `rewriteengine on` directive from the sub-folders the cookie-based redirect works again.

How can I make the cookie-based redirect work without actually going to the individual subfolders and adding it there?

Answer (score 0):

use the following for the rewrite rule:

```
rewriterule ^.*$ .set-cookie.php [R=302,L]
```